# Implementing hierarchical data structures with JPA (fixed depth)

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, orm

I have a hierarchical data structure with a fixed depth of 4. For a better understanding, let's assume the following (just an example):

- The "root" level is called *countries*
- Each country contains an arbitrary amount of *states*
- Each state countains an arbitrary amount of *counties*
- Each county contains an arbitrary amount of *cities*

So there are always 1-N relationships between the levels.

***A very important usecase*** (given the id of a country) is to load the whole "content" of a country at once with the smallest possible impact on the performance of the database.

In a first naive approach, I created 4 entitiy classes in Java where the entity "Country" contains a list of the type "State", the entity "State" contains a list of the type "County" and so on...
But what JPA creates afterwards are of course not 4 tables, but 7 (4 for the entities + 3 for the connection between the levels due to 1-N). I don't know if this is a good solution since there is a lot of joining going on under the hood.

I also tried to map the subtypes to their parent types (a city belongs to one county, a county belongs to one state, a state belongs to one country). This results in 4 tables, but makes it more difficult to retrieve all data at once from the application's point of view. If I'm not wrong, I would need 4 different requests instead of one.

How could I solve this problem? Is there a way to combine a simple table layout (with four tables, not seven) with easy to use entity classes (a parent type should know its children)?
If not, how would you realize this?

I'm using JPA with Hibernate and PostgreSQL.

Comment: A country is very different from a city. Are your entities also different at each level, warranting a table of their own, or are they more similar? If they are similar, take a look at nested sets. Inserts are intricate but selects are blazing fast, a single select rather than a couple joins. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007148/how-to-reflect-nested-sets-model-in-jpa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid the 3 extra mapping tables by using the `@JoinColumn` annotation rather than the `@JoinTable` annotation that I suspect you are using.

So for example:

**COUNTRY**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="country")
private List<State> stateList;
```

**STATE**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="country_id")
private Country country
```

The database tables would be as follows:

**Country**

```
country_id => primary key
```

**State**

```
state_id => primary key
country_id => foreign key
```

This way the mapping tables between all the 4 entities can be avoided.

Comment: FetchType.EAGER means you will be eagerly fetching country's entire structure, not good for performance. Let's say this data is displayed on a page that lists's all countries, that means you'll be retrieving the entire world (whatever is stored in those tables) just to show a few records. If you need to fetch it eagerly, then do it just for a single country, use a JPQL's JOIN FETCH to control when to lazy/eager fetch.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this pretty easily using JPQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM Country country
JOIN FETCH country.states states
JOIN FETCH states.counties counties
JOIN FETCH counties.cities cities
WHERE country.id = :countryId
```

Using `fetchType = FetchType.EAGER` on `@OneToMany`/`@ManyToOne`(believe that one is already `EAGER` by default) will achieve similar results.

Answer (score 2):

You already have the solution: four table is the way to go, with bidirectional relationships (use the `mappedBy` property in the not-owning side of every relationship). If the relationships are `EAGER`-fetched, than all entities are automatically loaded. If you want to use `LAZY` fetching, you could try a named query in order to load the entity with all relationships loaded:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Country c LEFT JOIN FETCH c.states s LEFT JOIN FETCH s.counties co...
```

Comment: "bilateral" -> "bidirectional".  The word "bilateral" is normally only used for relations between nations!

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple use bidirectional mapping. Go through that link

[How to delete Child or Parent objects from Relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569970/how-to-delete-child-or-parent-objects-from-relationship)

Make some changes like below

Country Entity:

```
------

@OneToMany(mappedBy="Country ",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<States > states;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="Country ",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Counties> counties;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="Country ",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Cities> cities;
-------
setters & getters
```

States  Entity:

```
-----
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="countryId")      
private Country country ;
-----
```

Counties Entity:

```
--------
 @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name="countryId")      
 private Country country ;
 -------
```

Cities Entity:

---

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="countryId")      
private Country country ;
---------
```

After compilation of all entity's do your insertion . Only 4 will create and read your data by using Country object id.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to declare the fetch type of the relations explicitely to eager with your second approach (default is lazy, that's why you have to do four queries).

E.g.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn ...
private ...;
```

see here: http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/fetch_hibernate_annotation

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your entities will look like:(You can use EAGER Loading instead of LAZY as well if you want)

### Entity: Country

```
@Id
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY_ID") 
private List<State> stateList;
```

### Entity: State

This table has COUNTRY_ID that is Foreign Key to Country

```
@Id
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="STATE_ID") 
private List<County> countyList;

@Column(name="COUNTRY_ID")
private Integer countryId;
```

### Entity: County

This table has STATE_ID that is Foreign Key to State

```
@Id
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTY_ID") 
private List<City> cityList;

@Column(name="STATE_ID")
private Integer stateId;
```

### Entity: City

This table has COUNTY_ID that is Foreign Key to County

```
@Id
private Integer id;

@Column(name="COUNTY_ID")
private Integer countyId;
```

Your JPQL will be:

`Select o from Country o where o.id=10`

This will pick The Country Entity along with all the mappings like below.

```
Country
  Holding List of States
    Each States Holding List of Counties
      Each Counties Holding LIst of Cities
```

Answer (score 1):

For a requirement like yours, I would suggest to have a tree-like structure to maintain the hierarchical location data. It is relatively easy to implement & maintain and is more scalable & extensible.

In order to implement tree you need to have 2 tables `LOCATION_NODE` (Location ID, Location Name, Location Type[country, state, county, city]) & `LOCATION_REL` (Relation ID, Parent ID, Child ID). Below is the basic implementation of the tree idea.

```
public class LocationRel<T> {
    private LocationNode<T> root;

    public LocationRel(T rootData) {
        root = new LocationNode<T>();
        root.data = rootData;
        root.children = new ArrayList<LocationNode<T>>();
    }

    public static class LocationNode<T> {
        private T data;
        private LocationNode<T> parent;
        private List<LocationNode<T>> children;
    }
}
```

This is the basic building block for a tree. You may need to add methods for add to, removing from, traversing, and constructors. But, once implemented, you have the freedom to add any new location type, change the hierarchy, add node, delete node etc with your hierarchical data.

Think out of the box.

Shishir

Answer (score 1):

If you need the performance, I would suggest to de-normalize your tables and create 4 entities with following attributes (columns):

1. Country: id, name
2. State: id, countryId, name
3. County: id, countryId, stateId, name
4. City: id, countryId, stateId, countyId, name

(mapping is obvious)

Then you will be able to build a simple SQL queries. 
If you need performance, prefer named queries as they are compiled at initialization time.
E.g. select all cities by country: "SELECT id, name FROM city WHERE country_id=?"

You may even not declare a references between entities using @ManyToOne, but just declare a simple @Columns. API call will, most likely, accept IDs (countryId, stateId), so you'll be better to pass that IDs as parameters to DAO. Most likely, you have a locations tables filled in once by sql script and the data should not be modified. Create foreign keys to guarantee data integrity.

And do you really need a tree-like structure in memory? If so, create it by hand, it is not very complex.

Answer (score 0):

Searching Online, I found a couple of Links on JPQL which I think might help.

[Link 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html#bnbri)

[Link 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html)

Anyways,

`JPQL` is one of the best ways to achieve this, try out this Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT country FROM Country country JOIN FETCH country.states states JOIN FETCH states.counties counties JOIN FETCH counties.cities cities WHERE country.id = :countryId
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that is useful, if you have relations that point to their parent only is the following:

With records:

```
@Entity
public class Country
{
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class State
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false) 
    Country country;
}

@Entity
public class County
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false) 
    State state;
}

@Entity
public class City
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "county_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false) 
    County county;
}
```

You can get all cities of a country with:

```
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long>
{
    List<City> findByCounty(County county);    // county is a direct field of City

    @Query("SELECT c FROM City c WHERE c.county.state.country = ?1")
    List<City> findByCountry(Country country);
}
```